# Single Table Inheritance with Sunspot/Solr and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, mongoid, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I have following classes in a Rails app:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Sunspot::Mongoid

  belongs_to :user

  searchable do
    text :name
    string :user_id
  end
end

class Post::Image < Post
  searchable do
    text :location
    time :taken_at
  end
end

class Post::Link < Post
  searchable do
    text :href
  end
end
```

As far as I know, calling following should just work.

```
Post.search do
  fulltext('something')
  with(:user_id, user.id)
end
```

But it does not. It returns an empty result. Calling `Post::Link.search` does also not work:

```
# => Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError: No field configured for Post::Link with name 'user_id'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I have a few subclasses that inherit from one parent, so all the subclasses go into the parent's mongodb collection. All of them are indexed, and I can search each subclass individually via sunspot. Can't search all of them at once via the parent though, which is the behavior I want. I think it has something to do with the fact that we're using Mongoid. This seems to work normally with ActiveRecord. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah, I switched from Sunspot/Solr to Tire/ElasticSearch, which is imho much better. Be sure to checkout RailsCasts [#306](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1) and [#307](http://railscasts.com/episodes/307-elasticsearch-part-2)!